# GridView must be added to a form tag for rendering

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

```
TextWriter tr = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(tr);
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
form.Controls.Add(divQueryDescription);
divQueryDescription.RenderControl(writer);

<div runat="server" id="divQueryDescription">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grv"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

My GridView is inside a DIV and I add that DIV to an HtmlForm, so that I can render it to a string. But I get the following error:-

Gridview 'grv' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server, although my Gridview is already inside a form because I added my DIV to the form.

How can I render this DIV to a string ?

Comment: Please post complete form design.

Comment: @Muhammad There is no form in the html of page. I am creating the Form dynamically because I need to email that content.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address what I think was overlooked earlier; please, though, refrain from posting your question twice just to get more attention to it - the extra data in your other question may be edited into the body of this one to bring it up to date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343630/gridview-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runat-server-even-after-the-grid

Comment: @Muhammad: This will render the complete Form and not that DIV. Everything including Form Tag , viewState etc. will get rendered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the following code in your page

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
  return;
}
```

To learn more about it, read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx).

Comment: I have don't have this method to override in my case. Because I have my DIV on a UserControl.

Comment: Overwrite it in the page hosting your UserControl - I have not tried it but that should do the trick

Comment: You may also need to invoke it from the UserCotrol code using page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(this)

Answer (score 0):

From what you show us here, the `GridView` *isn't* already in a `form` element with `runat="server"`, you need to do something like this:

```
<form runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="divQueryDescription">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grv"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

Of particular note is the `<form runat="server">` part, and its ending tag.

Update:

It looks like the `form` is causing problems because it hasn't been written out, you're writing out from the `div` directly: try using `form.RenderControl(writer);`.

Comment: I have added the DIV to HtmlForm dynamically...please see the code again..and the GridView is inside that DIV ..so isn't that GridView automatically added to that Form's Controls collection ?

Comment: If I directly add the GridView to the HtmlForm's Controls Collection, this exception disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have runat="server" in your form element/control