# GridView must be placed inside a form tag with runat="server" even after the GridView is within a form tag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

```
<form runat="server" id="f1">
    <div runat="server" id="d">
        grid view:
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="g">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="t" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class ScriptTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g.DataSource = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        g.DataBind();

        TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);    
        d.RenderControl(h);
        t.Text = tw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Even the GridView is within a from tag with runat="server", still I am getting this error.

Any clues please ?

Comment: I've seen this before if someone is using a Master page that already has a form tag (that may or may not already be declaring `runat="server"` in it's `<form>` tag). Just a thought...

Comment: @Lloyd: But I don't have any Master Page, I have created this page for testing this error only.

Comment: Hi, I copied your code but cannot replicate the problem. Can you please put the whole file contents (every line) into your question, or Pastebin it? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [GridView must be added to a form tag for rendering.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342393/gridview-must-be-added-to-a-form-tag-for-rendering)

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You are calling `GridView.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter)`, hence the page raises an exception that a Server-Control was rendered outside of a Form.

You could avoid this execption by overriding [VerifyRenderingInServerForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx)

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
  /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
     server control at run time. */
}
```

See [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1016960.aspx/1?Problem%20with%20GridView%20s%20RenderControl) and [here](http://aspalliance.com/771_CodeSnip_Exporting_GridView_to_Excel).

Comment: I have a GridView whose contents I want to render into an Email Message, thats why I need to render it out of form. I can not override this method because the host page is of Sharepoint. My Grid is a Usercontrol inside a web part in sharepoint page.

Comment: Also, when I add that GridView directly to an HtmlForm dynamically, and then render it, it perfectly renders. This means that it only requires the presence of a form outside grid. But, when I add that DIV to the HtmlForm dynamically, this error again comes, although the Grid is a child of DIV and also added to HtmlForm along with it.

Comment: this will not work if your grid is inside an .ascx user control. in that case see Chris Mullins answer below. I have used both Tim and Chris's techniques and they work great.

Comment: Worked great. Just a heads up you may get an error saying "RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();" If so set make sure to set the EventValidation  to false in the markup for the page.

Answer (score 30):

An alternative to overriding VerifyRenderingInServerForm is to remove the grid from the controls collection while you do the render, and then add it back when you are finished before the page loads. This is helpful if you want to have some generic helper method to get grid html because you don't have to remember to add the override.

```
Control parent = grid.Parent;
int GridIndex = 0;
if (parent != null)
{
    GridIndex = parent.Controls.IndexOf(grid);
    parent.Controls.Remove(grid);
}

grid.RenderControl(hw);

if (parent != null)
{
    parent.Controls.AddAt(GridIndex, grid);
}
```

Another alternative to avoid the override is to do this:

```
grid.RenderBeginTag(hw);
grid.HeaderRow.RenderControl(hw);
foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
    row.RenderControl(hw);
}
grid.FooterRow.RenderControl(hw);
grid.RenderEndTag(hw);
```

Comment: Adroit!! I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: when trying to render the grid inside an asp user control (.ascx), using the 1st method worked great for me.

Comment: 1.It doesn't work if gridview contains controls like LinkButton - it gives 'Control of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server' error. 2.Could you please explain why does this technique work?

Comment: @BornToCode Disable sorting for your gridview in code.

Answer (score 14):

Just after your Page_Load add this:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
}
```

Note that I don't do anything in the function.

EDIT: **Tim** answered the same thing. :)
You can also find the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334382/usercontrols-rendercontrol-is-asking-for-a-form-tag-in-c-net/338061#338061)

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add another way of doing this. I've seen multiple people on various related threads ask if you can use VerifyRenderingInServerForm without adding it to the parent page.

You actually can do this but it's a bit of a bodge.

First off create a new Page class which looks something like the following:

```
public partial class NoRenderPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        //Allows for printing
    }

    public override bool EnableEventValidation
    {
        get { return false; }
        set { /*Do nothing*/ }
    }
}
```

Does not need to have an .ASPX associated with it.

Then in the control you wish to render you can do something like the following.

```
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    var page = new NoRenderPage();
    page.DesignerInitialize();
    var form = new HtmlForm();
    page.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Controls.Add(pnl);
    controlToRender.RenderControl(hw);
```

Now you've got your original control rendered as HTML. If you need to, add the control back into it's original position. You now have the HTML rendered, the page as normal and no changes to the page itself.

Comment: @DanielEdwards what does DesignerInitialize() do for you?

Comment: This works but I needed to use `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);` to write the HTML - calling `controlToRender.RenderControl(hw);` didn't raise any of the controls events e.g `Page_Load` so whilst the control was rendering, it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is My Code

```
protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gvDetail.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite1 = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite1 = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite1);
            gvDetail.RenderControl(htmlWrite1);

            gvDetail.AllowPaging = false;
            Search();
            sh.ExportToExcel(gvDetail, "Report");
        }
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
           server control at run time. */
    }
```

Comment: Why did you add this answer 5 years after it was answered? And it is the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Schmelter's answer helped me a lot, but I had to do one more thing to get it to work on my aspx page.  I am using this code to email an embedded GridView control (as HTML), for report automation.

In addition to adding the override sub, I had to do the render() in Me.Handles.onunload, or else I got an error on the RenderControl line.

```
Protected Sub Page_After_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
If runningScheduledReport Then

    Dim stringBuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim stringWriter As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter(stringBuilder)
    Dim htmlWriter As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWriter)
    Dim htmlcode As String = stringBuilder.ToString()
    
    Func.SendEmail(Context.Request.QueryString("email").ToString, htmlcode, "Auto Report - Agent Efficiency", Nothing)

End If
End Sub
```