# Export ASP.Net grid data to excel w.o. third party dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to export grid data from ASP.Net webpage to Excel without using any third party dll.

can anybody tell me how to do it ?

Comment: With _export to excel_ you mean it can be html or do you   want to create a real excel file?

Comment: Have you considered exporting your data into a CSV file? This format is handled well by Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested you if u use any Control in Template Field of GridView Like Bullted List, RadioButtonList , CheckBoxList and  you want to export in Excel as it is then only use following code ...

```
public void ExportToExcel(GridView gv, string filename)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename + ".xls"));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                //  Create a table to contain the grid
                Table table = new Table();

                //  include the gridline settings
                table.GridLines = gv.GridLines;

                //  add the header row to the table
                if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
                {
                    // PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);

                    table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
                }
                //Make Header Coloruful

                for (int j = 0; j
```

Otherwise I would like to suggest DataTable which u bind Grid use that to export data in Excel.. And to do that use following Code.

```
 public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            //**************************Excel Generation starts***************************

            string attachment = "attachment; filename="+fileName+".xls";
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            string tab = "";

            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");

            int ik;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                tab = "";
                for (ik = 0; ik
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi PLease use below code to export to excel:

```
 FileInfo FI = new FileInfo(Path);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
DataGrid DataGrd = new DataGrid();
DataGrd.DataSource = dt1; //This is the same dataTable by which you are binding your grid
DataGrd.DataBind();

DataGrd.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
string directory = Path.Substring(0, Path.LastIndexOf("\\"));// GetDirectory(Path);
if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}

System.IO.StreamWriter vw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Path, true);
stringWriter.ToString().Normalize();
vw.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
vw.Flush();
vw.Close();
WriteAttachment(FI.Name, "application/vnd.ms-excel", stringWriter.ToString());
```

The above code uses a WriteAttachment function which pushes the attachment to the user in the Response object. The following code shows the implementation of WriteAttachment:

```
public static void WriteAttachment(string FileName, string FileType, string content)
{
    HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
    Response.ContentType = FileType;
    Response.Write(content);
    Response.End();
}
```

For more detail please [Click Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/477436/Export-Gridview-Data-to-Excel-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: He wants to export an existing `GridView` (not a `new DataGrid()`). You should also mention that this creates html which can be interpreted by excel, but actually it's not a recommandable format. Apart from that you need to override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`, otherwise `DataGrd.RenderControl` raises an exception. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343859/284240

Comment: agreed for `VerifyRenderingInServerForm()`