# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException occurred in mscorlib.dll occuring persitently

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im new to .net,
Im using the following code to transfer from gridview to excel:

```
         protected void toexcelbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "attendancedatereport.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    HtmlForm htmfrm = new HtmlForm();
    GridView1.Parent.Controls.Add(htmfrm);
    htmfrm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
    htmfrm.Controls.Add(GridView1);
    htmfrm.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());

    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

When i run this code,i get an exception:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

But,when i run the same code in another page for another gridview,it works perfectly.,i tried,adding

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
```

to the aspx page, and

```
<pre lang="cs">public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
   /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}</pre>
```

to the aspx.cs page,

i tried clearing the temporary files, still i get the same error,for more than 5hours i have tried,nothing is working.

I then tried select the **Debug** -> **Exceptions** menu item, and in the dialog that appears, checked the first checkbox for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions,

i get this error:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mark\3f229106\f785abea\App_Web_0h5ppn4m.dll' is denied.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will happen due to this:

```
Response.End();
```

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx):

> To mimic the behavior of the End method in ASP, this method tries to raise a [ThreadAbortException] exception. If this attempt is successful, the calling thread will be aborted, which is detrimental to your site's performance. In that case, no code after the call to the End method is executed.

So your `Response.Clear` call is pointless - and you should *expect* to see the `ThreadAbortException`, which you can ignore in this case.

If you need to call `Response.Clear` *at all*, it should be before you write to it - but I suspect you're fine to just remove it entirely.

Comment: @user2740323: That doesn't make it correct... you should always make sure you *understand* whatever code you're using, and validate that it makes sense.

Comment: even if i remove respose.clear(); and response.end() i ge this erro:A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Comment: @user2740323: I didn't suggest that you remove `Response.End`, only `Response.Clear`. And the `HttpUnhandledException` should have an inner exception - it's really important that you improve your diagnostic skills so that you can tell what's going wrong. Make sure you've got appropriate logging so that you can see full stack traces.

Comment: im new to .net,so,can pls tell me how i can perform logging

Comment: @user2740323: No - I suggest you take a step back, and learn about ASP.NET from a good book or tutorial. Trying to do so in a Stack Overflow comment thread for a question which isn't even about logging isn't appropriate. You might want to look at ELMAH though: https://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Answer (score 0):

First, i would  use an excel-ibrary like [EPPlus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx)(GPL) which i can warmly recommend.

Then it is as easy as this to create  real excel-files and write it to the `Response`, e.g.:

```
Dim pck = New ExcelPackage()
Dim ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet-Name")
ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium1)
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelFileName.xlsx")
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
```

Here is another example: http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

---

Reverse the `Response.Clear` + `Response.End`, `Clear` should be first and `End`  last:

```
try {
    Response.Clear();
    // ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //log error
}
// use HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); instead  
Response.End();
```

[HttpResponse.End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx)

> Sends all currently buffered output to the client, stops execution of
>   the page, and raises the EndRequest event.

Note that you also should use override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` to avoid an exception if you're trying to render the `GridView`.

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
  /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
     server control at run time. */
}
```

[GridView must be placed inside a form tag with runat="server" even after the GridView is within a form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343630/gridview-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runat-server-even-after-the-gri)

---

**Edit**:

But instead of `Response.End` you can use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`:

http://scottstoecker.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/fixing-threadabortexception-when-using-response-end/

Comment: i tried using:HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); now i get" A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' occurred in System.Web.dll"

Comment: @user2740323: Have you also overridden `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`?

Comment: yes i have,i also added EnableEventValidation="false" to page directive @Tim Schmelter

Comment: the thing i cant understand is,the same code works fine in 3other pages,but,its showing error in this page alone.

Comment: @user2740323: Have you noticed that `ThreadAbortException` is a different exception than `HttpUnhandledException`? So probably you have solved one issue.  Does your `HttpUnhandledException` provide more informations what happened? Have you used the debugger to go through each line  and inspect all relevant variables(f.e. the datasource of the gridview)? At which line do you get the exception at all?

Comment: see my edited code,in the question in that,after the last line( HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();) is executed,i could see the error in my OUTPUT window.