# How to export asp grid view inside a user control to excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I have a GridView in a WebUserControl in a web page thast uses a master page, and I need to export the grid data to excel and pdf.
I found this code:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportedHtml.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
this.EnableViewState = false;
System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
((GridView)Hosts.FindControl("hostsGrid")).RenderControl(hw);
Response.Write(tw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Control 'CPH_Body_Hosts_hostsGrid' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside 
a form tag with runat=server.
```

Even though I have a form runat server on the Master page.

Comment: There is quite a lot of articles about the topic. The error says exactly what you have to do in your user control aspx file, you have to enclose the gridview with a form, which usually is not what you want. It also depends on how you want it to look in the excel. We have been dealing with this issue for couple of months now and finally decided to write our own export which only takes the grid datasource. The drawback is that it is really hard to use the grid's filters and paging and reflect it in the export.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GridView must be placed inside a form tag with runat="server" even after the GridView is within a form tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343630/gridview-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runat-server-even-after-the-gri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found 2 solutions for this problem:

1. As King.code commented, it was already solved in [GridView must be placed inside a form tag with runat=“server” even after the GridView is within a form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343630/gridview-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runat-server-even-after-the-gri)
2. I also found this sample code that exports in many other formats [Export GridView to doc/access/csv/Excel/pdf/xml/html/text/print](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Export-GridView-to-07c9f836)